# I am not able to upload images and form data to rest api using DIO package in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I am not able to upload image to rest api in flutter I have checked the api its working fine.

I am not able to convert the file (image) to a uploadable form, can any one help me with that?
I have run flutter doctor -v everything is fine :)
Here is the code I am using to post form data:

```
Future<void> uploadAccountDetails(AccountDetailsModel details) async {
    var url = baseUrl + '/api/uploads/images';
    try {
      Dio dio = new Dio();
      FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap(
        {
          'city': details.cityName,
          'country': details.countryName,
          'residence_address': details.address,
          'dob': details.dob,
          'id_num': details.id,
          'passport_num': details.passportNo,
          'driving_license_nim': details.drivingLicNo,
          'user_id': 162,
          'postal_code': details.postalCode,
          'id_pic': await MultipartFile.fromFile(details.idPic.path,
              filename: basename(details.idPic.path)),
          'driving_license_pic':
              await MultipartFile.fromFile(details.drivingLicPic.path,
                  filename: basename(
                    details.drivingLicPic.path,
                  )), 
          'birth_certificate': await MultipartFile.fromFile(
            details.drivingLicPic.path,
            filename: basename(details.birthCertPic.path),
          ),
          'residence_permit_pic': await MultipartFile.fromFile(
            details.resPermitPic.path,
            filename: basename(details.resPermitPic.path),
          ),
          'profile_pic': await MultipartFile.fromFile(details.profilePic.path,
              filename: basename(details.profilePic.path)),
        },
      );
      print(formData);
      Response response = await dio.post(
        url,
        data: formData,
        onSendProgress: (received, total) {
          if (total != -1) {
            print((received / total * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%");
          }
        },
      );
      print(response.statusCode);
      // print(response);

    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      throw (e);
    }
  }
```

The logs of error are as follows:

> I/flutter (22523): DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error
>   [500] I/flutter (22523): DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status
>   error [500]

The status error is:

> I/flutter (22523): DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error
>   [500]

I searched this error but didnt find any solution, can anyone help me with that?

Comment: What application you trying API? Postman? Insomnia?

Comment: I am using postman to test my API

Answer (score 0):

I used dio for post a file path with some other information in this way:

```
  Dio dio = new Dio();
  FormData formData = new FormData();
  formData.add(
  "apiKey",
  "my_api_key",
  );
  formData.add(
  "file",
  "image_path",
  );
 Response response = await dio.post(
"https://localhost",
data: formData,
onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
  // do something
},
).catchError((onError) {
 throw Exception('something');
});
```

Comment: There is no method for Formdata object in Dio package i am using which version of Dio did you used?